# How to rename 'dist' folder with version number of package.json automatically in Jenkinsfile

Tags: node.js, shell, jenkins, automation

This is my package.json file

```
  "name": "@company/sdk",
  "version": "1.0.15",
  "description": "Made with create-react-library",
  "author": "me",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "repository": "https://gitlab.com/company/sdk",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
}
```

This is a step in Jenkinsfile

```
      steps {
         withEnv(["TOKEN=${NPM_REGISTRY_TOKEN}"]) {
             sh 'echo "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${TOKEN}" >> ~/.npmrc'
             sh 'npm publish'               
             sh 'mv /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/sdk-js_master/dist /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/sdk-js_master/1.0.15'
     }
   }
```

Everytime version number in package.json will change. How can I rename "dist" folder with same version number of package.json automatically.Right now I am manually renaming 'dist' folder to version number as shown on above Jenkinsfile. For example if package.json version number is 1.0.16 then I should rename dist folder to 1.0.16 automatically for deployment reason. I tried with sed and awk commad but didn't worked. Can anyone help with this complex issue.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved by script

```
#!/bin/bash
package_json_version=$(grep version package.json | cut -d '"' -f4)
echo $package_json_version
mv -v dist "$package_json_version"
mv /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/sdk-js_master/dist /var/www/assets/sdk-js_master/v$package_json_version
```